# Regex "until but not including" for special characters (using R)

Tags: regex, r

I have a data frame(RNA.patients) like this:

```
PAK1|5808
PAK2|10289
PALM2|114299
PALM2-AKAP2|445815
```

And I want to grab everything until "|", so I found this regex:

```
regmatches(RNA.patients[i,1], regexpr("^[^[:punct:]]*", RNA.patients[i,1]))
```

but for the cases like this "PALM2-AKAP2", the regex stops at "-". 
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Try figuring out what the regular expression is doing. It is matches until `[:punct:]` which is *any* punctuation. You should be able to change it so that it is just `|` pretty easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going with the [comment by @nograpes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127549/regex-until-but-not-including-for-special-characters-using-r#comment29995377_20127549), you could use a regex combined with `sub` to eliminate all characters from the pipe onwards.

```
sub("\\|.*$","",RNA.patients[[1]])
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of fussing with regular expressions (unless they are really necessary) just use `read.table` on the column to split it in two and extract the relevant column from there:

```
Text <- c("PAK1|5808", "PAK2|10289", "PALM2|114299", "PALM2-AKAP2|445815")
read.table(text = Text, sep = "|")
#            V1     V2
# 1        PAK1   5808
# 2        PAK2  10289
# 3       PALM2 114299
# 4 PALM2-AKAP2 445815
```

Or, you can use `strsplit`:

```
sapply(strsplit(Text, "[|]"), `[[`, 1)
# [1] "PAK1"        "PAK2"        "PALM2"       "PALM2-AKAP2"
sapply(strsplit(Text, "[|]"), `[[`, 2)
# [1] "5808"   "10289"  "114299" "445815"
```

Comment: @user3018573 - If you don't want to use regular expressions, try not to use the `regex` tag.

Comment: @sln you are rude here. The OP is trying a regular expression in his own solution so the use of regex tag is normal here. I guess he chooses this answer because it is jsut simpler and the R way to do this task...

Comment: @agstudy - The OP stated he wanted to grab everything "until the first bar". He showed his regex, his question was on regular expressions, his first tag was `regex`. No indication he is looking to split records on bar, yet he accepts as the answer a simple string split on a literal which doesn't specifically answer his direct question on the regular expression problem he is having. I will be avoiding R tag questions.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could move the negation into the punct sub-class, then add - to the outer class

`^[-[:^punct:]]*`

if you want to globally match just the fields, use this

`[-[:^punct:]]+`

Comment: +1! it is always challenging to get a regular expression. Here, we should set `perl=TRUE`, `regmatches(Text,gregexpr('[-[:^punct:]]+',Text,perl=TRUE))`

Comment: [:punct:] is POSIX not Perl.

Comment: But negated POSIX class [:^punct:] is a Perl extension.